# No specific subroutine for MPI_CART_CREATE

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am trying to play around with the topology of my mpi implementation but I  am running into errors using `MPI_CART_CREATE`.

The sample Fortran code

```
use mpi

implicit none
integer :: ierror, nproc, ring_comm

call MPI_INIT(ierror)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierror)
call MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1, nproc, .false., 1, ring_comm, ierror)

call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
```

produces the error:

```
call MPI_CART_CREATE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1, nproc, .false., 1, ring_comm, ierror)
                                                                       1
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic 'mpi_cart_create' at (1)
```

I can not figure out why this error is produced as all the reference documents indicate this is the correct form.  Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard (and given [here](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node401.htm) for one version) the binding for the subroutine is

```
MPI_CART_CREATE(COMM_OLD, NDIMS, DIMS, PERIODS, REORDER, COMM_CART, IERROR)
INTEGER COMM_OLD, NDIMS, DIMS(*), COMM_CART, IERROR
LOGICAL PERIODS(*), REORDER
```

The code in the question uses

```
MPI_CART_CREATE(COMM_OLD, NDIMS, DIMS, PERIODS, REORDER, COMM_CART, IERROR)
INTEGER COMM_OLD, NDIMS, DIMS, COMM_CART, REORDER, IERROR
LOGICAL PERIODS
```

So:

- There is a wrong type for `reorder`;
- `ndims` and `periods` are scalars, not arrays.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I really messed up the order and type of the arguments. fixed now, thx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't passing the correct arguments here. You can find a [man page](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Cart_create.html) for this function. I'd suggest tracking down a good tutorial for MPI topologies since that's a topic way to big for an answer here. A quick Google search revealed quite a few, but this one was near the top and in Fortran: http://scv.bu.edu/~kadin/Tutorials/Alliance/MPI/virtual_topology/cart_example2.html.